# Use Pycharm and Spyder Together

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

Recently i read this comment 
I like Spyder for interacting with my variables and PyCharm for editing my scripts. Alternative Solution: use both simultaneously. As I edit in PyCharm (on Mac OS), the script updates live in spyder. Best of both worlds!

i want to understand how to use them together and live update the script in Spyder ?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I find that there is no variable explorer like Sypder option in PyCharm. To work with PyCharm and Spyder together, we need to use the two IDEs parallelly i.e., to write the code we can use the PyCharm and to view the Spyder we can just alt tab to the Spyder window and re run the code in Spyder. It will not take much time to re run the code again. We just need to press Ctrl + A and Ctrl + Enter, then the variables will get updated in the variable explorer. Spyder variable view is amazing especially data frames.

Only thing we need to remember is, we need to install the packages in both PyCharm and Sypder. If we install the package in PyCharm, it will not reflect in Spyder. So we need to install through Conda Prompt.